# how many epochs required for model with lstm training

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am having nn Actor Critic TD3 model with LSTM in my AI.
For every training, I am creating batches of sequential data and training my AI.

Can someone expert please help to let know if I require epochs as well for this AI.And in general how many epochs can I run with this code, because I am creating many batches on one training step is it feasible to have epochs as well.

Below is training step code

```
def train(
        self,
        replay_buffer,
        iterations,
        batch_size=50,
        discount=0.99,
        tau=0.005,
        policy_noise=0.2,
        noise_clip=0.5,
        policy_freq=2,
        ):
        
        b_state = torch.Tensor([])
        b_next_state = torch.Tensor([])
        b_done = torch.Tensor([])
        b_reward = torch.Tensor([])
        b_action = torch.Tensor([])

        for it in range(iterations):

            # print ('it: ', it, ' iterations: ', iterations)

      # Step 4: We sample a batch of transitions (s, s’, a, r) from the memory

            (batch_states, batch_next_states, batch_actions,
             batch_rewards, batch_dones) = \
                replay_buffer.sample(batch_size)

            batch_states = batch_states.astype(float)
            batch_next_states = batch_next_states.astype(float)
            batch_actions = batch_actions.astype(float)
            batch_rewards = batch_rewards.astype(float)
            batch_dones = batch_dones.astype(float)

            state = torch.from_numpy(batch_states)
            next_state = torch.from_numpy(batch_next_states)
            action = torch.from_numpy(batch_actions)
            reward = torch.from_numpy(batch_rewards)
            done = torch.from_numpy(batch_dones)

            b_size = 1
            seq_len = state.shape[0]
            batch = b_size
            input_size = state_dim

            state = torch.reshape(state, ( 1,seq_len, state_dim))
            next_state = torch.reshape(next_state, ( 1,seq_len, state_dim))
            done = torch.reshape(done, ( 1,seq_len, 1))
            reward = torch.reshape(reward, ( 1, seq_len, 1))
            action = torch.reshape(action, ( 1, seq_len, action_dim))
            
            b_state = torch.cat((b_state, state),dim=0)
            b_next_state = torch.cat((b_next_state, next_state),dim=0)
            b_done = torch.cat((b_done, done),dim=0)
            b_reward = torch.cat((b_reward, reward),dim=0)
            b_action = torch.cat((b_action, action),dim=0)
            
            # state = torch.reshape(state, (seq_len, 1, state_dim))
            # next_state = torch.reshape(next_state, (seq_len, 1,
            #         state_dim))
            # done = torch.reshape(done, (seq_len, 1, 1))
            # reward = torch.reshape(reward, (seq_len, 1, 1))
            # action = torch.reshape(action, (seq_len, 1, action_dim))
            
            # b_state = torch.cat((b_state, state),dim=1)
            # b_next_state = torch.cat((b_next_state, next_state),dim=1)
            # b_done = torch.cat((b_done, done),dim=1)
            # b_reward = torch.cat((b_reward, reward),dim=1)
            # b_action = torch.cat((b_action, action),dim=1)
                                                      
        print("dim state:",b_state.shape)

      # for h and c shape (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size)

        ha0 = torch.zeros(lstm_layers, b_state.shape[0], state_dim)
        ca0 = torch.zeros(lstm_layers, b_state.shape[0], state_dim)
        hc0 = torch.zeros(lstm_layers, b_state.shape[0], state_dim + action_dim)
        cc0 = torch.zeros(lstm_layers, b_state.shape[0], state_dim + action_dim)
        # Step 5: From the next state s’, the Actor target plays the next action a’
          
        b_next_action = self.actor_target(b_next_state, (ha0, ca0))
        b_next_action = b_next_action[0]
  
        # Step 6: We add Gaussian noise to this next action a’ and we clamp it in a range of values supported by the environment
          
        noise = torch.Tensor(b_next_action).data.normal_(0,
                policy_noise)
        noise = noise.clamp(-noise_clip, noise_clip)
        b_next_action = (b_next_action + noise).clamp(-self.max_action,
                self.max_action)
  
        # Step 7: The two Critic targets take each the couple (s’, a’) as input and return two Q-values Qt1(s’,a’) and Qt2(s’,a’) as outputs
        
        result = self.critic_target(b_next_state, b_next_action, (hc0,cc0))
        target_Q1 = result[0]
        target_Q2 = result[1]
  
        # Step 8: We keep the minimum of these two Q-values: min(Qt1, Qt2)
          
        target_Q = torch.min(target_Q1, target_Q2).double()
          
        # Step 9: We get the final target of the two Critic models, which is: Qt = r + γ * min(Qt1, Qt2), where γ is the discount factor
          
        target_Q = b_reward + (1 - b_done) * discount * target_Q
          
        # Step 10: The two Critic models take each the couple (s, a) as input and return two Q-values Q1(s,a) and Q2(s,a) as outputs
          
        b_action_reshape = torch.reshape(b_action, b_next_action.shape)
        result = self.critic(b_state, b_action_reshape, (hc0, cc0))
        current_Q1 = result[0]
        current_Q2 = result[1]
          
        # Step 11: We compute the loss coming from the two Critic models: Critic Loss = MSE_Loss(Q1(s,a), Qt) + MSE_Loss(Q2(s,a), Qt)
          
        critic_loss = F.mse_loss(current_Q1, target_Q) \
            + F.mse_loss(current_Q2, target_Q)
          
        # Step 12: We backpropagate this Critic loss and update the parameters of the two Critic models with a SGD optimizer
          
        self.critic_optimizer.zero_grad()
        critic_loss.backward()
        self.critic_optimizer.step()
          
        # Step 13: Once every two iterations, we update our Actor model by performing gradient ascent on the output of the first Critic model
        
        out = self.actor(b_state, (ha0, ca0))
        out = out[0]
        (actor_loss, hx, cx) = self.critic.Q1(b_state, out, (hc0,cc0))
        actor_loss = -1 * actor_loss.mean()
        self.actor_optimizer.zero_grad()
        actor_loss.backward()
        self.actor_optimizer.step()
  
        # Step 14: Still once every two iterations, we update the weights of the Actor target by polyak averaging
          
        for (param, target_param) in zip(self.actor.parameters(),
                self.actor_target.parameters()):
            target_param.data.copy_(tau * param.data + (1 - tau)
                    * target_param.data)
  
        # Step 15: Still once every two iterations, we update the weights of the Critic target by polyak averaging
          
        for (param, target_param) in zip(self.critic.parameters(),
                self.critic_target.parameters()):
            target_param.data.copy_(tau * param.data + (1 - tau)
                    * target_param.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I will say this, generally reinforcement learning requires A LOT of training. This is however heavily dependent on the complexity of the problem you are trying to solve. The situation may be made worse if your model is complicated (e.g. when using a LSTM). When training an agent to play Atari games you can expect needing up to 1 million episodes (depending on the game and the approach used).

With regard to epochs, if you mean repeated use of a particular episode (or collection of episodes) for training then it will depend on whether your using an on or off policy approach (for off policy this is like experience replay, epochs is the wrong word). Actor-Critic methods are generally on policy, which means they require fresh data at each stage of training. Once an episode has been used for training it should not be used again. For more information about the difference between on/off policy I recommend taking a look at [Sutton's book](http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html).